# Remove a disk from RAID1 without reinstalling system

Tags: raid1

I have a remote server with 2 disks (2000 GB each) connected using software RAID1.
Can I somehow disconnect the second disk from RAID and use it independently for storage **without reinstalling system (Ubuntu) and keeping the data on the first disk**?

cat /proc/mdstat:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
  499392 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
  7996416 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sda4[0] sdb4[1]
  1944881152 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
  bitmap: 1/15 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk
```

fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 83BCC898-32B3-432D-B4E3-87B3995B386C

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2      4096    1003519     999424  488M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3   1003520   17004543   16001024  7.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  17004544 3907028991 3890024448  1.8T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A0DBD375-0E50-4C5A-A7A7-9584D2BF8950

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2      4096    1003519     999424  488M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3   1003520   17004543   16001024  7.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  17004544 3907028991 3890024448  1.8T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/md2: 1.8 TiB, 1991558299648 bytes, 3889762304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 7.6 GiB, 8188329984 bytes, 15992832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md0: 487.7 MiB, 511377408 bytes, 998784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

*Technically*, the removal of a disk from RAID 1 would count as a failed drive. It would continue functioning, but in a "degraded" state. It is *theoretically* possible, however, a bad idea in practice. Your best bet is to copy the files elsewhere if you can, even doing a drive clone.

If you can't do a drive clone to a spare hard drive, pull one, format it, duplicate files, use that as the main.

But *please*, back up your files, and don't assume the word of someone on the internet is law.

On the flipside, something something HW RAID ftw.